# Gerrit - Introduction of new drop-down list box for Code Review Classification

Tags: gerrit

Is it possible to Customize Gerrit to introduce a new field in the review Comments window with a drop-down list values ?

Or by using triggers in gerrit?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to configure the Gerrit review comments windows to add drop-down lists. I think you're trying to select default / common / more used comments in a drop-down list, aren't you? Maybe it'll be better if you use hooks to execute automated verification instead. Please, take a look at the [Git::Hooks](http://search.cpan.org/~gnustavo/Git-Hooks-1.12.4/). We use it and it's really nice.